# ConfigParser inexisting file exception

Tags: python

Since Python's ConfigParser does not throw an exception if the file does not exist, is it fine to do it this way:

```
try:
    config = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser()
    if config.read('/home/me/file.conf') != []:
        pass
    else:
        raise IOError('Cannot open configuration file')
except IOError, error:
    sys.exit(error)
```

Comment: Won't that also throw if the file exists, but is empty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. you should try to put as little as possible inside the try block
2. There isn't a whole lot of point to throwing an exception just to catch it on the next line.